# What is the business term equivalent to 'wait my turn' or 'wait in a queue'?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a short and effective term to express the behavior of 'waiting for his business'. I would like to use it in business organizational contexts like below:

> The administrators often request that the engineers <strike>for taking</strike> take a look at a systems glitch but they always end up suffering from the 'waiting for their turn'.

Comment: I’m not completely sure I understand your question, but “waiting in line” is an American English version of “waiting on queue.” If they’re waiting for a person, they’re “waiting on him.” More informally, “twiddling their thumbs.”

Comment: @Davislor: We don't say "waiting on queue" in the UK. "On cue" is an entirely different kettle of fish. We normally "Wait **for**" someone, though "waiting **on**" someone is still colloquial in some parts of the UK.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Huh. I have heard it before, but I guess my sources were out of date.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK we **queue** for things, or **queue up** for them or **join the queue** for them. Or we *wait our turn*.

- When there is a systems glitch, the administrators often ask the engineers to take a look at it. But they always find themselves [placed] in a queue.

Or, slightly different:

- When there is a systems glitch and the administrators request an engineer to examine it, they always find themselves [placed] in a queue.

Or "...always find themselves at the back of a queue." Or "...always end up having to join the queue". In the US, as Davislor says, it's "to wait in line."